# Jquery DatePicker YearRange based on current month

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using Jquery's Datepicker and I want to know if it's possible to change the yearRange atribute based on the current month.

In my case, if the month it's different from november or december yearRange its the current year

else it's the current year + 1

**Example 1:**

current month: april

```
.datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-12:+0'
```

**Example 2:**

current month: november

```
.datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../../App_Themes/Samae/images/calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-12:+1'
```

thanks!

Comment: I have only managed to verify the month in javascript and then a simple if/else condition to see which example it should fit... I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this

Comment: More elegent... You store a variable and set it when creating the `datepicker` options. `yearRange: isDecOrNov`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***jQuery code***

```
$(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var range;
    if (month == 10 || month == 11) {
        range = '-12:+1';
    } else {
        range = '-12:+0';
    }
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: range
    });
});
```

You can check it working out by changing the condition as `if (month == 03 || month == 11)`.

***Alternate***

```
$(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: (month == 10 || month == 11) ? '-12:+1' : '-12:+0'
    });
});
```